Is "divisioning" a standard English word?
I have been using the word divisioning to mean "separating into divisions" or "making into divisions." While it sounds correct to me, I am not a native English speaker and would like to confirm if it is a standard word in English.
I searched for "divisioning meaning" on Google, but the results only provided definitions for division, with no mention of divisioning.

Is "divisioning" a recognized English word? If not, what would be a more appropriate term to convey this meaning?
If it's not recognized English word, should it be added to the vernacular with the definition being "to make into divisions"?


Example usage: Is divisioning of a country based on the political system used?

The verb related to the noun division is divide!

Yes, Kate is right. [sighs about the question]

@KateBunting I am aware of that, but how would you modify the provided example?

By using dividing instead, of course.

I could see "divisioning" being used in some contexts, such as making the word from the noun division when representing, say, an army division: "The general staff worked all afternoon divisioning the leftover troops" (meaning assigning them to divisions). Yeah, English is flexible enough for that. But for other purposes it would be better to use divide as the verb, as Kate says.

Checking in a dictionary or three is the starting point for addressing question (1). Question (2) is inappropriate; acceptability, acceptance into the lexicon, is usage-driven not usefulness-driven. The two often do not correspond, or do so only after a considerable time has elapsed. ELU does not deal with protologisms / suggested additions to the lexis.

I mean there is a difference between providing and provisioning.

Wiktionary has a definition of divisioning (n.): "A dividing up; allotment into divisions". If you search "divisioning of" in Google Books, you can find many examples also, mainly in technical contexts.

Something like partitioning is probably more standard, but precise context will matter. If a "division" is an administrative subunit, then divisioning would be the best word. If by "division" you just mean "part" or "section" then probably you want something nicer-sounding. Question is a bit too vague.

We don't "use" political sytems.

@TimR "choose"? "adopt"?

"have adopted"  would be better.

In effect, you are proposing to use "division" as a verb. While you could do it, the verb "divide" already exists, and it is flexible enough to be used as you would like to use "division". For instance, you might say, in military usage, "A corps is divided into divisions." For other uses, you might say, "The face of a clock is divided into 12 divisions, each representing one hour." So, condensing this to "A clock face is divisioned into 12 hours," is possible but that doesn't really make much improvement, so adoption of the term is unlikely.

I will take the view that in certain contexts divisioning (by  analogy with partitioning etc) would be better than divide. For example, a national collegiate sports association might have a meeting to discuss "redivisioning"; or there might be a course on holding company organization theory at a university business school where approaches to corporate divisioning are examined from various angles.
The context would have to justify it.
Here are some attestations.

But ELU deals with verifiable usages, and expressly not protologisms.

This is a verifiable usage, as the attestations attest.  And the variety of uses clearly indicates that it is not a protologism.  Usage has extended well beyond its original users, whoever they may have been.  There are attestations from the 19th century.

Now it's more than what comes across as an unsupported conjecture. I'd say it's still not ideal to use, especially as it is already used with various meanings which can't be found in dictionaries.

I was offering an opinion on the usage of  divisioning and the sort of contexts that might justify its use over divide,  responding to the view that the verb form divisioning was "unuseful"; I added attestations when your comment made me realize that the fact it has been in use for a long time needed to be entered into evidence. I was thinking of the many inane yet countenanced, even welcomed, single word requests here on ELU when I made the "shite" remark.

Dictionaries tend to omit what their editors regard as domain-specific jargon; but divisioning is used in a wide variety of domains and deserves an entry.

Dictionaries tend to omit the unidiomatic, which includes the very unidiomatic.

idiomatic applies to expressions (in vivo usages) not individual words.

Look it up.  'Pertaining to idioms' is not the default definition. Idiomatic: 'using, containing, or denoting expressions that are natural to a native speaker.' [OED, courtesy of Google]. And expression: 'a word or group of words used in a particular situation or by particular people:' [CD] Covered on ELU before.

I don't think you're interpreting that definition of expression correctly in respect to "single word".  "Yikes" is a single-word "expression". divisioning is not.

The department has divisions.

We made or created those divisions.
We divided it into separate areas.

to make or create divisions.
divided into divisions is a no-go.
English allows for creating words such as divisioning but it is not useful in this context.

Please disregard the downvote. This usage is accurate.
